# dynamic custom layout for lightning community

Tags: lightning-community

I am trying to create a dynamic custom layout for the lightning community where I can set rows and columns of the layout. 
I tried creating layout by implementing force community: layout but I didn't find a way where I can get input for a number of rows and columns
also I am not able to create attributes of type Aura.Component[] dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SF.SE. The general approach to building a component like this would be to create a number of components that incrementally build the functionality needed for the final component. At a minimum, you'd want a "row" component, a "column" component, a table, and most likely a grid component plus a container to hold everything. You'll want to define attributes for rows and columns. You'd need a means of handling your data as an array to send it into each row and column.

I hope this helps you get started. In the future, when you post a question like this, please include any code you've written and where you're stuck. Questions posted without code typically get closed. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thank you for your reply but it didn't worked as if we create a new component inside layout we cant drag and drop another component inside it.  I need a approach where i can dynamically create aura attributes.